# found raw type: JComboBox

Tags: java, jcombobox

I have very simple source file GuiApp1.java which I am trying to compile with cmd javac.
It gives me warning that :

```
C:\Users\Thakkar\Java>javac GuiApp1.java
Note: GuiApp1.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

so I used cmd as javac -Xlint GuiApp1.java for compile the source file.

it gave me 6 warnings
e.g.

```
GuiApp1.java:48: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: JComboBox
        JComboBox fruits = new JComboBox(fruitOptions);
        ^
  missing type arguments for generic class JComboBox<E>
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class JComboBox
```

how can i solve this?

Comment: Its warning, you can don't worry about this ), but you have to read books about java, especially part about generics for understanding what compiler want from you.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from Java 7 many Swing components use generics, so older code will produce a warning for raw types.

For the combobox example you can eliminate the warning if you provide the type of the objects it holds e.g. you should use `JComboBox<String> fruits = new JComboBox<>(fruitOptions);` if `fruitOptions` is a `String[]`. If you use some other type change it accordingly.